# IPhone Event sent from child thread to main thread through method dispatch_async, slow, try to improve.

Tags: iphone, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread

App receives event from child thread, but we need to send it to main thread to do UI update issue, current now use method dispatch_async, dues to main thread is very busy, for some case it will cost two or three seconds to arrive at the destination, slow, try to improve, but so far no better method found, any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ handleLoginOK(value); });
```

Comment: We use event bus model, receive event from child thread, in order to do corresponding UI change according to the event, we need to send the event data to main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntillDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) it may or may not be faster, I am not completely sure.

Comment: Have tried, a little faster, not much improvement, the precondition is that main thread is always very busy which is a factor that the delay is so obviously.